# How to add session cookie in weevely?

Tags: web-application, backdoor

I am pentesting a website and I was successful in uploading a php backdoor and finding the path of the backdoor. The only issue is that in order to gain access to the uploaded file I need to be logged in with my account.
i can do this by adding my session cookies in weevely but how can I add my session cookies in weevely to access the backdoor file? Is there a way to do this or is it possible?

Comment: Did you search online? https://github.com/epinna/weevely3/issues/38

Comment: @multithr3at3d Yes I saw that issue but I cannot understand what he was saying, sorry I am also new in this field

Comment: @multithr3at3d Can you help me out how and where to add that additional header?

Comment: I've never used the tool before, but in the issue they say they edited "config.py". Searching for that in the repository, it's here https://github.com/epinna/weevely3/blob/master/core/config.py